# compile twisted in pyInstaller

Tags: python, twisted, pyinstaller

I'm currently looking into pyInstaller. I've been using py2exe for now but it would be nice if I'm only using one compiler for all platforms we target. My py2exe setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    name='agent',
    description='Service Test',
    version='1.00.00',
    service=['agent'],
    console=['agent.py'],
    zipfile=None,
    options={ "py2exe":{
                    "includes":"win32service,win32serviceutil,win32event,servicemanager,autobahn",
                    "packages": 'twisted, autobahn',
                    'bundle_files': 1
                },
        },
)
```

I've managed to compile the windows service but as soon as i start using twisted it fails.
Commanlines I've used to compile with pyInstaller:

```
python PyInstaller.py --onefile c:\path\here\agent.py
python PyInstaller.py --hidden-import=twisted --onefile c:\path\here\agent.py
```

The error I get when I try to install my service

```
agent.exe?175104\twisted\python\modules.py:758: 
UserWarning: C:\dist\path\agent.exe?175104 (for module twisted.web.util) not in path importer cache (PEP 302 violation - check your local configuration).
```

Comment: It says "UserWarning" not "UserError" - in other words, it probably isn't fatal.  Does your service work?  If not, what did you expect to happen and how did what happened differ from that expectation?

Comment: Service fails to start

Comment: Hi, sorry, this isn't enough information for me to provide a good answer.  Please see http://sscce.org/